# Druid.io: update/override existing data via streams from Kafka (Druid Kafka indexing service)

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, druid

I'm loading streams from Kafka using the **Druid** [Kafka indexing service](https://docs.imply.io/on-premise/tutorial/kafka-indexing-service).

But the data I uploaded is always changed, so I need to reload it again and avoid duplicates and collisions if data was already loaded.

I research docs about [Updating Existing Data](http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/update-existing-data.html) in Druid.

But all info about Hadoop Batch Ingestion, [Lookups](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/lookups.html) .

Is it possible to update existing Druid data during Kafka streams?

In other words, I need to rewrite the old values with new ones using **Kafka indexing service** (streams from Kafka).

May be any kind of setting to rewrite duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

Druid is in a way a time-series database where the data gets "finalised" and written to a log every time-interval. It does aggregations and optimises columns for storage and easy queries when it "finalises" the data.

By "finalising", what I mean is that Druid assumes that the data for the specified interval is already present and it can safely do its computations on top of them. So this in effect means that there is no support for you to update the data (like you do in a database). Any data that you write is treated as a new data and it keeps adding to its computations.

But Druid is different in the sense it provides a way to upload historical data for the same time period the real-time indexing has already taken place. This batch upload will overwrite any segments with the new ones and further queries will reflect the latest uploaded batch data.

So I am afraid the only option would be to do batch ingestion. Maybe you could still send the data to Kafka, but have a spark/gobbin job that does de-duplication and write to Hadoop. Then have a simple cron job to re-index these as a batch onto Druid.